# Getting Acquaintances to become Friends

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Some times when you trade with an acquaintance you get a prompt asking if you want to be friends with the other person. Most of the times it does not. It happens randomly too. It could be  after the first trade  after just trading 1 pokemon or it could happen after the 3rd trade request with that person after trading 10 pokemon.

When and how can I get the friend request to appear?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Player_Search_System):

> The main window of the PSS divides other players in three categories: Friends, Acquaintances, and Passersby. A Passerby will automatically become an Acquaintance if a Battle or Trade (including Wonder Trades ) is made with him/her: **after trading or battling with a player already in the Acquaintances, a prompt to add them to the Friends group will appear**.

So it seems that 2 Battle/Trades are needed in order to get the prompt.

Comment: ninten's answer will work but you can also get/add friend codes from the main 3DS menu in the friend list screen. Pokemon x/y will add anyone in that list to the friends list in the game.

Comment: I am sorry it doesn't always work that way, and that is the point of the question. It is unknown if it will ask you to be friends with an aquaintance after a trade/battle. I found this using a google search and as you see it does not help.

Comment: @DarylF - A well known fact but does not answer my question.

Comment: @SamyamA I know, this answer is just how it is supposed to work. Let's wait for someone else to report a similar problem, otherwise you should assume that your game or internet connection is faulty.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my game, my DS or my Internet connection. Assuming random things is not the answer to anything.

Comment: @SamyamA Might have something to do with the parental controls and how/whether they were set up on either your or your acquaintance's system, maybe?

Comment: @TrentHawkins - I have not set up any parental controls on my system. But it really seems random to me sometimes. But we all know such things are usually not random, and that is why I have put up this question.

Comment: I didn't get a friend request prompt either. I originally traded with someone through GTS, this someone became an aquaintance. A day later, I specifically requested a trade with this person and successfully traded, but no prompt, no new friend, no nothing.

Comment: Shot in the dark, as I never tried the GTS myself: the requested user is the one who initially gets the prompt after a trade/battle, and the requester will ONLY get the prompt if the other user has accepted to be friends in the first place. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @ninten, I have a feeling you're right, but can't confirm it. I have no friends :(